# Function to sum the products of two table columns if first cell contains certain text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Need to check the first column of a table for the text string "Mechanical" in order to only work with those rows; then multiply two columns in the same table and finally sum all the products. Basically a SUMPRODUCTIF

Formula I'm trying to use:

```
=IF(Table2[Team]=C4, SUMPRODUCT(Table2[Normal working hours],Table2[Position salary per hour]),"")
```

Also:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(Table2[Team]=C4,Table2[Normal working hours],""),IF(Table2[Team]=C4,Table2[Position salary per hour],""))
```

Note: `C4` is where "Mechanical" is found in another table.

I have also attempted using a `SUM` with two `IF` statements multiplied within.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second formula you have tried should work. Please check if there is any spelling mistakes or blank spaces in the data.

Comment: I was posting my own answer just as you posted yours. 
You're correct I found I had to flank it with curly brackets by pressing `cntrl + shift + enter`